# How can I combine segmentation and encoding to create a repeatable pipeline using sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a machine learning model using mixed data types. My data is loaded into a pandas dataframe, and I would like to create a pipeline to encode the data, along the following lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer, QuantileTransformer, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

df = pd.DataFrame({'client_id' : range(65),
                   'client_city' : ['Austin']*30+['Dallas']*10+['Tempe']*25, 
                   'client_state' : ['Texas']*40 + ['Arizona']*25,
                   'subscription_type' : ['business']*20 + ['personal']*20 + ['business']*2 + ['personal']*23, 
                   'monthly_fee' : np.random.random(65)*20 + 50})

categorical_features = ['subscription_type']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

numerical_features = ['monthly_fee']
numerical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()) #### Replace this part
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
        ('num', numerical_transformer, numerical_features)
    ],
    sparse_threshold=0,
    remainder='passthrough'
)
```

The issue is that in the data, there are regional variations in the `monthly_fee` by `client_city` and `client_state`, so applying `StandardScaler` on the entire dataset at once would lose significant regional information (e.g., a high monthly payment in Cheap Town, NY would be considered very moderate in New York, New York). At the same time, some cities have sparse data (say < 20 clients), so it makes sense to take averages at the state or national level.

I've been getting around this problem by training encoders on subsets of the data like so:

```
df.set_index(['client_city','client_state','subscription_type','client_id'], inplace=True)
df['monthly_fee_scaled'] = np.nan
grp_by_city = []
grp_by_state = []

for ii, grp in df.groupby(level=[0,2]):
    N = grp.shape[0] # number of clients in this city
    if N>=20:
        power_tran = PowerTransformer()
        grptmp = grp[['monthly_fee',]].copy()
        grptmp['monthly_fee_scaled'] = power_tran.fit_transform(grp[['monthly_fee',]])
        grp_by_city.append(grptmp)
    else:
        pass

tmp = pd.concat(grp_by_city)
df.update(tmp)

for ii, grp in df.groupby(level=[1,2]):
    N = grp.shape[0] # number of clients in this state
    if N>=20:
        power_tran = PowerTransformer()
        grptmp = grp[['monthly_fee',]].copy()
        grptmp['monthly_fee_scaled'] = power_tran.fit_transform(grp[['monthly_fee',]])
        grp_by_state.append(grptmp)
    else:
        pass

tmp = pd.concat(grp_by_state)
df.update(tmp, overwrite=False)
```

This is hacky, but it worked well for an initial proof-of-concept. But now I want to do it right and persist the encoding/model so I can process new data. Ideally, there would be a way to do segmentation+encoding using sklearn pipelines, but I have not been able to google up or figure out a solution. Is there a nice way to handle this?

Comment: Hi, could you post some sample data so that others can better see your code formulation and also look into this themselves?

Comment: Thanks @WR, I added a sample data frame! My real data has more columns/categories, I'm trying to keep it readable...